# Import error whlie importing 'emoji' package in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am facing the following import error while importing 'emoji' package in python :

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import emoji

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\emoji_*init*_.py in 
16
17
---> 18 from emoji.core import *
19 from emoji.unicode_codes import *
20

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\emoji\core.py in 
14 import sys
15
---> 16 from emoji import unicode_codes
17
18 **all** = [

ImportError: cannot import name 'unicode_codes' from 'emoji' (C:\Users\KUSH\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\emoji_*init*_.py)

I am working on Windows 10. What should I do in order to rectify this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the 'emoji' package.
The steps are

```
git clone https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji.git
cd emoji
python setup.py install
```

if you're working on Linux ubuntu.

But, you're working on Windows so that you have to access this link [Emoji Github](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji.git) and then down load the files. Then, on your command prompt(cmd window), you should be in your folder for you to download it using `cd` command.

Finally, you can execute this.

```
python setup.py install
```

If it doesn't work, you can execute this too(if you have pip).

```
pip install unidecode
```